# Creating Standard Normal Distribution Curve with 26 years of Price Data

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I am attempting to create a standard normal distribution and graph it with 26 years of price data from Crude Oil.  I've managed to create the graph; however, i'm not sure if it's correct and it's not smooth.  I used monthly data so as to keep the population to 319.  It could be the way i'm graphing it in excel, but the graph isn't very readable.  Is there a better way to show this data? I haven't worked with standard deviation and normal distribution in quite some time so I apologize if I am making an obvious mistake or interpreting the data wrong.  **My end goal is to demonstrate where current prices are relative to the entire data set.**

Given that my data set does not contain any zero/negative numbers the mean should be the highest point on the curve with 0 being the left bound and my max being the right bound.

[Current Graph of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chRZT.gif)

**

**Data Calculations**

- Min = 11.35
- Max = 133.88
- Mean = 46.56
- STDEV.P = 30.73832725
- (Mean-5*STDEV.P) = -107.1336425
- (Mean+5*STDEV.P) = 200.24963
- (200.24963- -107.1336425)/15

  **Data Set**

21.10
22.86
22.11
20.39
18.43
18.20
16.70
18.45
27.31
33.51
36.04
32.33
27.28
25.23
20.48
19.90
20.83
21.23
20.19
21.40
21.69
21.89
23.23
22.46
19.50
18.79
19.01
18.92
20.23
20.98
22.39
21.78
21.34
21.88
21.69
20.34
19.41
19.03
20.09
20.32
20.25
19.95
19.09
17.89
18.01
17.50
18.15
16.61
14.52
15.03
14.78
14.68
16.42
17.89
19.06
19.66
18.38
17.45
17.72
18.07
17.16
18.04
18.57
18.54
19.90
19.74
18.45
17.33
18.02
18.23
17.43
17.99
19.03
18.86
19.09
21.33
23.50
21.17
20.42
21.30
21.90
23.97
24.88
23.71
25.23
25.13
22.18
20.97
19.70
20.82
19.26
19.66
19.95
19.80
21.33
20.19
18.33
16.72
16.06
15.12
15.35
14.91
13.72
14.17
13.47
15.03
14.46
13.00
11.35
12.52
12.01
14.68
17.31
17.72
17.92
20.10
21.28
23.80
22.69
25.00
26.10
27.26
29.37
29.84
25.72
28.79
31.82
29.70
31.26
33.88
33.11
34.42
28.44
29.59
29.61
27.25
27.49
28.63
27.60
26.43
27.37
26.20
22.17
19.64
19.39
19.72
20.72
24.53
26.18
27.04
25.52
26.97
28.39
29.66
28.84
26.35
29.46
32.95
35.83
33.51
28.17
28.11
30.66
30.76
31.57
28.31
30.34
31.11
32.13
34.31
34.69
36.74
36.75
40.28
38.03
40.78
44.90
45.94
53.28
48.47
43.15
46.84
48.15
54.19
52.98
49.83
56.35
59.00
64.99
65.59
62.26
58.32
59.41
65.49
61.63
62.69
69.44
70.84
70.95
74.41
73.04
63.80
58.89
59.08
61.96
54.51
59.28
60.44
63.98
63.46
67.49
74.12
72.36
79.92
85.80
94.77
91.69
92.97
95.39
105.45
112.58
125.40
133.88
133.37
116.67
104.11
76.61
57.31
41.12
41.71
39.09
47.94
49.65
59.03
69.64
64.15
71.05
69.41
75.72
77.99
74.47
78.33
76.39
81.20
84.29
73.74
75.34
76.32
76.60
75.24
81.89
84.25
89.15
89.17
88.58
102.86
109.53
100.90
96.26
97.30
86.33
85.52
86.32
97.16
98.56
100.27
102.20
106.16
103.32
94.66
82.30
87.90
94.13
94.51
89.49
86.53
87.86
94.76
95.31
92.94
92.02
94.51
95.77
104.67
106.57
106.29
100.54
93.86
97.63
94.62
100.82
100.80
102.07
102.18
105.79
103.59
96.54
93.21
84.40
75.79
59.29
47.22
50.58
47.82
54.45
59.27
59.82
50.90
42.87
45.48
46.22
42.44
37.19
31.68
30.32
37.55
40.75
46.71
48.76

**

Comment: If you are just trying to show the distribution of prices, why not just use a histogram?

Comment: Why do you imagine the pricing is normal?  Oil tends to be seasonally cyclic, no?  Different means at different times of year...  And of course prices change with market conditions (inflation, for example).

Comment: @smcc I could just use a histogram.  To be honest I liked the idea of looking at data from a standard deviation standpoint, but I could do that as well.

Comment: @lulu It could not be normal; that's plausible as well. Crude is cyclic, but over such a large time period with monthly figures that's not going to be as prevalent unless I was using daily data.

Comment: Normal distributions are unimodal.  Seasonal pricing should be bimodal (or multimodal).  But the other point is more important...market prices don't follow static distributions over time.  There are wars, there's inflation.  I'd be really surprised if a single distribution gave any sensible description.

Comment: @lulu that is a great point.